# Sequelize Associations Not Working

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models post and comment. A post can have many comment and a comment can belong to a single post. Here is the classes generated using sequelize.

**post**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var post = sequelize.define('post', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        post.hasMany(models.comment)
      }
    }
  });
  return post;
};
```

**comment**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var comment = sequelize.define('comment', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    body: DataTypes.STRING,
    postId: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        comment.belongsTo(models.post)
      }
    }
  });
  return comment;
};
```

Here is the comment migration file:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.createTable('comments', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      body: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      postId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: "posts",
          key:"id"
        }

      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('comments');
  }
};
```

I don't have the relationship back from post to comment.

After that I create a post and then create a comment. Later I retrieve the comment and instruct to get the post associated with the comment when I get the error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeEagerLoadingError: post is not associated to comment!
```

Here is the code which I used:

```
// create a post object
/*
const post = models.post.build({
    title: "Hello World"
})

// save a new post
post.save().then(function(newPost){
  console.log(newPost)
})
*/

// create a comment
/*
const comment = models.comment.build({
   title: "Comment",
   body: "Body",
   postId : 1
})

comment.save().then(function(newComment){
  console.log(newComment)
}) */

// get the comment and also the post it belongs to
models.comment.findOne({
  include: [
    {
      model: models.post 
    }
  ]
}).then(function(comment){
    console.log(comment)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to handle rejection, to prevent Unhandled rejection error:

```
models.comment.findOne({
  include: [
    {
      model: models.post
    }
  ]
}).then(function (comment) {
  console.log(comment)
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

And about error description `"post is not associated to comment"`. It looks like you put wrong instance. Maybe you need to put comment instead of whole post:

```
include: [
  {
    model: models.post.comment
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

From the association you have created,
Post is associated to comment and not the other way round.

So you can do

```
Model.post.findAll({include:[model.comment]}
```

But not the other way round.
I would suggest you look into association more [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html)

Currently you have a 1:m relationship from post to comment. You will need an n:m association to do the other way round.